# "Token is null" using singleton for Context/Activity

Tags: android

I've implemented a singleton class to avoid pass Activity as parameter to every method/constructor.

```
public class ApplicationContext {

    private static class Holder {
        private static final ApplicationContext INSTANCE = new ApplicationContext();
    }

    private ApplicationContext() {}

    private Context mContext;

    public static ApplicationContext getInstance(){
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public Context getContext(){
        return Holder.INSTANCE.mContext;
    }


    public void setContext(Context mContext){
        Holder.INSTANCE.mContext = mContext;
    }
}
```

And in my initial activity, i set the context:

```
private void initializeObjects(){
    ApplicationContext.getInstance().setContext(getApplicationContext());
}
```

The problem happens when i try to use context in a ProgressDialog:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Salvando Usuário");
}
```

Error message:

```
07-05 20:29:46.413  30930-30930/com.test.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.test.app, PID: 30930
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:690)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:289)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:311)
        at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
```

Is a good practice to use a singleton like i've tried? What's wrong? If it's not, what is a good practice instead pass context/activity to every call?

Thank in advance.

Comment: What is `context`? Nothing posted here shows where this is assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AlertDialogs you cannot use any context that isn't an Activity so use something like Activity.this or getActivity() if you are in a Fragment.

You can still use the Application global context to get colors and drawables and other stuff, but for example creating a view with this context the theme is ignored so try to use the Activity context as much as possible.

By the way if you want to have a singleton where you can access the context, you should extend the Application class in the ApplicationContext and override the method onCreate, along with adding this ApplicationContext class to your manifest Application element name. If you use that initializeObjects method and call it from the first activity what would happen to that context when you exit that activity?

So as an example:

```
public class ApplicationContext extends Application {

    private Context mContext;

    public static Context getContext(){
        return mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       mContext = this;

       // you can initialize other stuff here if you want
    }

}

// manifest
<application
        android:name="com.example.ApplicationContext"
```

When the app is run, it always goes through the onCreate method of the Application class and it lives through the entire lifecycle of the app. But don't abuse it too much.

Comment: there is zero need to store a reference to mContext, application objects already have a context internally - this is absolutely redundant.

Comment: @apelsoczi what are you talking about? The Application class extends ContextWrapper that extends Context. Calling it the application own name or Context is the same thing except that it is much more clear to anyone that you are fetching a context to use freely somewhere